# Event code is not executed after default page reload

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

On onSubmit form event I'd like to send some data to the server with PUT or POST method and then refresh the page, but page reloads without executing the rest of the event code. Adding line `event.preventDefault()` fixes the issue but blocks reloading. What am I missing?

Event code:

```
handleFormSubmit = (event, requestType, articleID) => {
        const title = event.target.elements.title.value;
        const content = event.target.elements.content.value;
        switch ( requestType ) {
            case 'post':
                return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/', {
                    title: title,
                    content: content
                })
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(error => console.err(error));
            case 'put':
                return axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000  /api/${articleID}/`, {
                    title: title,
                    content: content
                })
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(error => console.err(error));
        }
    }
```

Form code:

```
 <Form onSubmit={(event) => this.handleFormSubmit(
                event,
                this.props.requestType,
                this.props.articleID )}>
            <FormItem label="Title" >
                <Input name="title" placeholder="Put a title here" />
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem label="Content" >
                <Input name="content" placeholder="Enter some content ..." />
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">{this.props.btnText}</Button>
            </FormItem>
            </Form>
```

Comment: Do you want to 'refresh' or 'reload' your page?

Comment: I want to reload the page

Comment: You're using axios to do the actual POST request to your API. So you probably want to reload manually after the promise resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to programmatically reload your page after the form has been submitted successfully, or show an error message when there is no response or any server error:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    return axios
      .post("https://reqres.in/api/login", {
        email: "title",
        password: "content"
      })
      .then(res => {
        alert(res.data.token);
        location.reload();
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a demo :https://codesandbox.io/s/j7j00nq705

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.preventDefault()`. But you should use `react-router` library `history.push()` to manually load another component after your request completes.

```
  case 'post':
             return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/', {
                    title: title,
                    content: content
             })
             .then(res => {
                  console.log(res);
                  // using "history.push()" to load another component
                  this.props.history.push('/somePage')
                  })
             .catch(error => console.err(error));
```

Your above `Form` component must be routed using react-router or `Form` component must be in a `Component` routed using react-router.